# Apple Mach-O Librarian Error compiling CocoaPods

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors

I can run my iOS app fine, but when I go to archive it I get this error message

```
   Libtool "/Users/segiddins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Random_Rainbow-czqebqncxgyefwepjkdltmqvzrhx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Sometimes Red, Sometimes Blue/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Pods.build/Objects-normal/armv7/libPods.a" normal armv7
    cd "/Users/segiddins/Dropbox/Dev/Random Rainbow/Pods"
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:/opt/local/bin:/Users/segiddins/bin:/Users/segiddins/.npm:/usr/local/go/bin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only armv7 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk "-L/Users/segiddins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Random_Rainbow-czqebqncxgyefwepjkdltmqvzrhx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Sometimes Red, Sometimes Blue/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos" -filelist "/Users/segiddins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Random_Rainbow-czqebqncxgyefwepjkdltmqvzrhx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Sometimes Red, Sometimes Blue/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Pods.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Pods.LinkFileList" -framework Foundation -o "/Users/segiddins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Random_Rainbow-czqebqncxgyefwepjkdltmqvzrhx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Sometimes Red, Sometimes Blue/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Pods.build/Objects-normal/armv7/libPods.a"

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file list file: /Users/segiddins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Random_Rainbow-czqebqncxgyefwepjkdltmqvzrhx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Sometimes Red (No such file or directory)
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Well aware now, but I don't know how to rename the project folder structure without breaking the xcodeproj

Comment: Create a new project, drag the files over (with good names) and do whatever setup is necessary. There may be easier methods but given the nature of SO this is the easiest to describe.

Comment: But wont that make my archives in xcode go into a different bucket?

Comment: There is always a price to pay for not following best practices—some sooner others later.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help. In the end, I unlinked the libPods framework, as I didn't really need the pod in the release, but I will follow your advice when I want to update the app.

Comment: Great! Note: I have been caught many times with similar mistakes. :-)

Comment: I think what tripped me up is that most of the build commands seem to put paths in quotes, whereas I dont think that ld command does

Comment: Exactly correct. This is much less of a problem than it used to be years ago but I am still wary of "funny" names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Sometimes Red, Sometimes Blue"
is a really bad name for a file in a development environment. Note the error:
"Sometimes Red (No such file or directory)"
and note that it is a partial file name, perhaps the "," in the name is causing a problem.

Best Practice: do not use spaces in file names -- or other "funny" symbols, make names pronounceable.

One rather drastic solution:
Create a new project, drag the files over (with good names) and do whatever setup is necessary. There may be easier methods but given the nature of SO this is the easiest to describe.